# After implementing google maps as fragment i don't get any error in the run block but the fragment doesn't bring up the map on my device

Tags: java, android, google-maps

App runs normally....but when ever i click on the icon that should brings up the maps fragment it remains on the current fragment

```
runtime block ::: /.example.findm: Unsupported class loader
W/.example.findm: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:412457): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=7011 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c174,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 19530035
W/.example.findm: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/.example.findm: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
```

[image of run time display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOdA5.png)

this is my git link to my app code https://github.com/wisdom3541/findme

Comment: Please read the Guideline on how to ask a Question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i tried my best explaining take a look at the image plss...... The map  fragment doesn't comes up when the icon is clicked and it doesn't show any error in the runtime block and the app doesn't crash.....that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `break` in the switch `case R.id.location` from your `onNavigationItemSelected` method in `menu.java`, which is why the app skips location and goes right to `case R.id.add_friends`.

Once you add a `break`:

```
case R.id.location:
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_cont, new currentlocation()).commit();
    break;
```

your Map Activity launches without problem when selected. Hope this helps! :)